# Power issue with NRF24LO1 and ATtiny44

Tags: power-supply, arduino, buck, attiny, nrf24l01

I am super frustrated with my NRF24LO1 module and ATtiny44. The thing is when it is connected to an Arduino board it works perfectly, but when I try powering up using battery the entire system halts.

I tried soldering a 10uF cap also across 3.3V and GND of NRF module, I have also used 10uF and 0.1uF capacitor across VCC and GND of ATtiny IC.

I tried a 13.8V, 5.4A rechargeable battery along with converter (LM2596 buck converter) to bring down the voltage to 5V for ATtiny. I used another LM and calibrated it to 3.3V for NRF module, it still doesn't work. I have also tried using diode chain and voltage divider.

Please let me know if you have solution.

Comment: Post schematics of what you have.

Comment: I assume the grounds are all connected. I would also like to see the schematic as you have wired it. I am assuming you are using a ATiney PCB, not the chip. Hint a Power Supply the Arduino is NOT!